# How do I import existing phpcodesniffer results into sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, phpcodesniffer

I'm starting out with Sonar. We've got about 10 custom sniffs in our own standard for PHP_Codesniffer and are using a subset of various sniffs of other standards. PHP_Codesniffer works like a charm and generates a report in Checkstyle format.

How can I get Sonar5.1 to import this codesniffer-results-in-checkstyle-format.xml file?

I heard this was possible in older versions of the PHP plugin, but I'm not sure if that relates to a ruleset.xml or to the actual results of the run.

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer possible to import external rules from tools like CodeSniffer, PHPDepend, ... The PHP Plugin rely now exclusively on SonarQube Rules Engine as it is mentioned here : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/PHP+Plugin and it provides out of the box [110 predefined rules](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#languages=php).
You can write as of now custom rules unless you customize directly the PHP Plugin.
If some rules are missing, you are more than welcome to share with us your suggestions.